# xslt 2/3 nested group with for-each-group maintaining input order

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

There are similar questions on stackoverflow but the answers sort or group the matching items putting them out of sequence compared to the order of the input.

I have the following data

```
<doc>
<paragraph indent="0" stylename="heading_l1_toc" SDgroup="heading">heading-l1</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="0" stylename="heading_l2_toc" SDgroup="heading">heading-l2</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="0" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">AAA. Para 1.</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="1" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">BBB. Para 2</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">BBB. Continued para1</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">BBB. Continued para2</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="2" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">CCC. Para 3a</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="2" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">DDD. Para 3b/4</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="1" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">EEE. Para 5</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">EEE. Continued para</paragraph>
<paragraph indent="0" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">FFF. Para 6</paragraph>
</doc>
```

I need to nest the paragraph[@stylename='list'} and following paragraph[@stylename='continued'] based on the list/@indent = x and the continued/@indent = x + 1.

The output should look like:

```
<doc>
  <paragraph indent="0" stylename="heading_l1_toc" SDgroup="heading">heading-l1</paragraph>
  <paragraph indent="0" stylename="heading_l2_toc" SDgroup="heading">heading-l2</paragraph>

  <List indent="0" maxItems="2">
    <paragraph stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">AAA. Para 1.</paragraph>
      <List indent="1" maxItems="1">
        <paragraph indent="1" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">BBB. Para 2</paragraph>
        <paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">BBB. Continued para1</paragraph>
        <paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">BBB. Continued para2</paragraph>
        <List indent="2" maxItems="2">
          <paragraph indent="2" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">CCC. Para 3a</paragraph>
          <paragraph indent="2" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">DDD. Para 34</paragraph>
        </List>
        <paragraph indent="1" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">EEE. Para 5</paragraph>
        <paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">EEE. Continued para</paragraph>
      </List>
      <paragraph indent="0" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">FFF. Para 6</paragraph>
  </List>
</doc>
```

I have tried many, many versions of for-each-group + group-by/adjacent and regular for-each, but end up with out of sequence output and/or correctly nested output but duplicate data (i.e. an item is correctly nested and then, at some point, the same item is output again. I believe this occurs with multiply nested for-each loops.

I'm 99.9% sure this is do'able but can't find a solution that produces what I need. Once again, I'm asking for help, which will of course, be greatly, greatly appreciated.

FYI: I have no control over the input data or means to change it - unless its within XSLT

Comment: It is not clear what the criteria are for starting/forming a list, at least not to me. The `<paragraph indent="1" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">BBB. Para 2</paragraph>` seems to start a `list`, why does the `<paragraph indent="1" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">EEE. Para 5</paragraph>` not start another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment, it's a little easier to understand your output; however, I suggest that your provided output doesn't follow your description because the `maxItems` for the second `List` element (just after `AAA` should be `2` and not `1` since there are two `list_unordered` elements that are immediate children of that `List` element.

I've reworked my example implementation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:l="local:functions"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="/doc" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:sequence select="l:processParagraphs('-1', *)" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="l:processParagraphs" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="indentLevel" as="xs:string"           />
        <xsl:param name="paras"       as="element(paragraph)*" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="head($paras)/@stylename eq 'list'
                            and
                            xs:integer(head($paras)/@indent) gt xs:integer($indentLevel)">
                <xsl:variable name="itemsUnderList" as="element(paragraph)*"
                              select="l:nextInList(head($paras)/@indent, $paras)" />
                <xsl:variable name="processedInner" as="element()*"
                              select="l:processInner(head($paras)/@indent, $itemsUnderList)" />
                <List indent="{head($paras)/@indent}" maxItems="{count($processedInner[@stylename eq 'list_unordered'])}">
                    <xsl:sequence select="$processedInner" />
                </List>
                <xsl:sequence select="l:processParagraphs($indentLevel, $paras except $itemsUnderList)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="l:processInner($indentLevel, $paras)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="l:processInner" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="indentLevel" as="xs:string"           />
        <xsl:param name="paras"       as="element(paragraph)*" />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="head($paras)" /> <!-- to replace list stylename -->
        <xsl:if test="tail($paras)" >
            <xsl:sequence select="l:processParagraphs($indentLevel, tail($paras))" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="paragraph/@stylename[. eq 'list']">
        <xsl:attribute name="stylename" select="'list_unordered'" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="l:nextInList" as="element(paragraph)*" >
        <xsl:param name="indentLevel" as="xs:string"           />
        <xsl:param name="paras"       as="element(paragraph)*" />

        <xsl:if test="xs:integer(head($paras)/@indent) ge xs:integer($indentLevel)" >
            <xsl:sequence select="(head($paras),
                               l:nextInList($indentLevel, tail($paras)))" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces:

```
<doc>
   <paragraph indent="0" stylename="heading_l1_toc" SDgroup="heading">heading-l1</paragraph>
   <paragraph indent="0" stylename="heading_l2_toc" SDgroup="heading">heading-l2</paragraph>
   <List indent="0" maxItems="2">
      <paragraph indent="0" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">AAA. Para 1.</paragraph>
      <List indent="1" maxItems="2">
         <paragraph indent="1" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">BBB. Para 2</paragraph>
         <paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">BBB. Continued para1</paragraph>
         <paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">BBB. Continued para2</paragraph>
         <List indent="2" maxItems="2">
            <paragraph indent="2" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">CCC. Para 3a</paragraph>
            <paragraph indent="2" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">DDD. Para 3b/4</paragraph>
         </List>
         <paragraph indent="1" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">EEE. Para 5</paragraph>
         <paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">EEE. Continued para</paragraph>
      </List>
      <paragraph indent="0" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">FFF. Para 6</paragraph>
   </List>
</doc>
```

Comment: this works VERY, VERY well. Thank you. Thank you. You have no idea how much sleep I've lost in attempting to attain this functionality.   I still don't fully understand how its working but I'm using my debugger to step through and look at the internals, but the output is what I was looking for. Thank you again.

Comment: The basic algorithm is that, while descending the items, we write out each one using **l:processParagraphs()** which, if we don't need a **<List>**, just calls **l:processInner()**. if we find a **list** and that **list** has an indent level greater than previous **list** levels, then we add a **<List>** element, update the **indentLevel** and then process recursively in **l:processParagraphs()** those items that will be part of that particular **<List>** (determined by **l:nextInList()**). (The function **l:nextInList()** could be simplified via a *:following-sibling* axis expression.)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out what your example was doing but I haven't quite nailed it.  In case this helps somewhat, I've taken a recursive function approach.

One thing that I'm not seeing in your example are series of increasing/decreasing/increasing indentation levels, so I don't have anything to check against, but the method that I'm submitting should handle that.

As @martin-honnen mentioned in his question, there is an ambiguity about how to handle the `list` type w.r.t. indentation.

Also, I have no idea what the rule might be for the `maxItems` attribute.

For what it's worth:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:l="local:functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/doc" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:sequence select="l:processParagraphs(head(*)/@indent, *)" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:function name="l:processParagraphs" as="element()*">
    <xsl:param name="indentLevel" as="xs:string"           />
    <xsl:param name="paras"       as="element(paragraph)*" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="head($paras)/@stylename eq 'list'
                      and
                      xs:integer(head($paras)/@indent) ge xs:integer($indentLevel)">
        <List indent="{head($paras)/@indent}" maxItems="???">
          <xsl:variable name="itemsUnderList" as="element(paragraph)*"
                        select="l:nextInList(head($paras)/@indent, $paras)" />
          <xsl:sequence select="l:processInner(head($paras)/@indent, $itemsUnderList)" />
          <xsl:sequence select="l:processParagraphs($indentLevel, $paras except $itemsUnderList)" />
        </List>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:sequence select="l:processInner($indentLevel, $paras)" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>    
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:function name="l:processInner" as="element()*">
    <xsl:param name="indentLevel" as="xs:string"           />
    <xsl:param name="paras"       as="element(paragraph)*" />
    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="head($paras)" /> <!-- to replace list stylename -->
        <xsl:if test="tail($paras)" >
          <xsl:sequence select="l:processParagraphs(head($paras)/@indent, tail($paras))" />
        </xsl:if>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="paragraph/@stylename[. eq 'list']">
    <xsl:attribute name="stylename" select="'list_unordered'" />
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:function name="l:nextInList" as="element(paragraph)*" >
    <xsl:param name="indentLevel" as="xs:string"           />
    <xsl:param name="paras"       as="element(paragraph)*" />
    
    <xsl:if test="xs:integer(head($paras)/@indent) ge xs:integer($indentLevel)" >
      <xsl:sequence select="(head($paras), 
                             l:nextInList($indentLevel, tail($paras)))" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:function>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces (in https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/)

```
<doc>
   <paragraph indent="0" stylename="heading_l1_toc" SDgroup="heading">heading-l1</paragraph>
   <paragraph indent="0" stylename="heading_l2_toc" SDgroup="heading">heading-l2</paragraph>
   <List indent="0" maxItems="???">
      <paragraph indent="0" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">AAA. Para 1.</paragraph>
      <List indent="1" maxItems="???">
         <paragraph indent="1" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">BBB. Para 2</paragraph>
         <paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">BBB. Continued para1</paragraph>
         <paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">BBB. Continued para2</paragraph>
         <List indent="2" maxItems="???">
            <paragraph indent="2" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">CCC. Para 3a</paragraph>
            <List indent="2" maxItems="???">
               <paragraph indent="2" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">DDD. Para 3b/4</paragraph>
            </List>
            <paragraph indent="1" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">EEE. Para 5</paragraph>
            <paragraph indent="2" stylename="continued" SDgroup="list">EEE. Continued para</paragraph>
         </List>
         <List indent="0" maxItems="???">
            <paragraph indent="0" stylename="list_unordered" SDgroup="list">FFF. Para 6</paragraph>
         </List>
      </List>
   </List>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thanks al-truisme. Apologies for my vague explanation.  maxItems should count  number of <paragraph stylename="list"> within that <List>

RE indents: source file is flat XML i.e. ALL elements are siblings within <doc>. Lastly, the output isn't quite right. Nested <List> is only created when indent value 
within <paragraph stylename="list"> is > previous indent

Para containing:
<paragraph indent="2" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">DDD. Para 3b/4</paragraph>

should be within the same <List> as:
<paragraph indent="2" stylename="list" SDgroup="list">CCC. Para 3a</paragraph>

Comment: this works VERY, VERY well. Thank you. Thank you. You have no idea how much sleep I've lost in attempting to attain this functionality.   I still don't fully understand how its working but I'm using my debugger to step through and look at the internals, but the output is what I was looking for. Thank you again.